# Integrating your app with google voice

Tags: java, android, integration, voice

I am a student developer working on a hands free texting solution for android. After much hard work, the app is finally complete and has been released on the market. However, the very first review I got from a user was a request for google voice integration.

Is there some way to integrate my app with voice? Is there a broadcast receiver or something that I could implement, and a way to send texts? After much googling, I an still unsure where to begin.

All that I need to be able to do is receive text messages from voice and then send out new ones in reply.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [unofficial Google Voice API for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/). There are also [example apps](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/wiki/ApplicationGallery).

Comment: So does that mean that the google voice app does not have any built in broadcast receivers that I could tap into?